# Perl/Tk Memory Leak When Using destroy() Command

Tags: memory-leaks, destroy, perltk

I am having an issue with a large leak in Perl/Tk running on Unix.  I am unable to post most of the code due to certain restrictions, but I have been able to identify what is causing the memory leak and create a small program that has the same symptoms.  Basically I am running a GUI where a frame is destroyed and repopulated regularly.  This seems to cause a large memory leak that keeps growing however.  I thought the destroy command would get rid of all traces in memory, but it does not seem to be that way.  I am not too familiar with the garbage collection in Perl either.  This program will be running for days or weeks at a time and so a memory leak is not ideal.  Does anyone have any ideas to stop the memory leak?  I am restricted to using Perl, so unfortunately I cannot just easily port the code to Python or something.  Thanks for help in advance.

```
#!opt/project/COTS/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

$Tk::mw = MainWindow->new;
$Tk::mw->repeat(10,\$build);
my $status;
&build;

sub build{
    $status->destroy() if ($status);
    $status = $Tk::mw->Frame->pack(-side => 'top');

    my $left_frame = $status->Frame(
        -relief =>'sunken',
        -borderwidth => 1
    )->pack(-side => 'left', -anchor => 'nw', -padx => 4, -pady => 5);

    my $right_frame = $status->Frame(
        -relief =>'sunken',
        -borderwidth => 1
    )->pack(-side => 'left', -anchor => 'nw', -padx => 4, -pady => 5);

}
MainLoop;
```

Comment: Really?  Nobody has any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is known. There are some leftovers in the Perl/Tk system when destroying a widget (actually it's not the fault of Perl, but of the Perl/Tk subsystem).

The best approach is to reuse widgets. Most of the time this is possible, as you can re-configure all options. If some subwidgets are about to vanish and reappear, then you can use `packForget()` to temporarily remove them from display, and use `pack()` again to make them visible.